# Convert TRUE or FALSE to Yes or No in REGEXMATCH

Tags: google-sheets

How to convert boolean True or False to "Yes" or "No" in Google Sheets?

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1;"word")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(A1,"word"), "Yes", "No")
```

Answer (score 1):

for a single cell:

```
=IF(A1="word"; "yes"; "no")
```

for a range of cells:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A10="word"; "yes"; "no"))
```